# Tailwind generating faulty class every time it compiles

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've made a typo once, where i wrote 2 classes without space `max-w-[412px]mb-[36px]` like this. It threw an error, so i put a space there. It still continued to throw the error, I proceeded to delete the two classes entirely, but it did not stop creating this class.

[image: faulty class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go and save your tailwind.config.js to invalidate all the cache and delete all unused classes from the stylesheet